# What is this cylindrical spring-containing drill-set accessory?

Tags: tools

A collection of drill bits contains three elements like the one in the picture below.  It's about 30mm high. 15mm outer diameter, and marked "ADW".  Internally it contains a spring with some flexible metal protrusions at the one end.  What is its use?

[image: Drill-set accessory]

In the complete set they are located on the right of four flat donut-shaped bits (also of unknown purpose), each containing an Allen screw to fix them on an axis.

[image: Complete drill set — side 1]

[image: Complete drill set — side 2]

Comment: Some form of ratchet?

Comment: I had an old drill bit sharpener that had a drill bit holder that looked a tiny bit like that, but if similar then pieces are missing.  Does the tool turn?  Can you twist the bottom and top sections?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I added a picture of the complete set. The other end is round (as shown in the second picture).

Comment: @crip659 The tool's outside is a single piece of plastic; it doesn't turn.

Comment: "four flat donut-shaped bits (also of unknown purpose), each containing an Allen screw to fix them on an axis." *Those* are depth stop collars. They clamp to a suitable sized drill bit so you can drill a hole of a certain depth, but no more (unless they slip...)

Comment: I also added the second side of the set, in case there's a relevant component there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black donuts are depth gauges, they go over the drill bits so you can drill holes to preset depth.

The blue things are screw holders I think, to hold screws against the driver bits.

Comment: I believe you're quite correct on the blue thing. You put a screwdriver bit in the drill, slip this over the end, then put the screw into the blue holder. Put the tip of the screw where you want it to go, and hold the blue collar while starting the screw. This allows you to hold the non-spinning blue collar, and it holds the spinning screw & driver bit for you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, and it seems to work in this way. All three screw holders are for the same size screws. It would have been more useful to have three different diameters for corresponding screws.

Comment: I'm glad you found those useful, @DiomidisSpinellis, I've never been able to make one work in any sort of meaningful way. Maybe it's just me...

Comment: Whan I wrote it "worked" I meant that piecing together the various elements gave me an assembly might do the intended job.  I've yet t use it for actually drilling.